# Queueable Apex: Unable to log exception to a custom error object

Tags: exception, queueable-apex

I am developing a Queueable class in Apex. This class is going to be used to feed data to salesforce from external systems.

I am seeing the following issue. I followed this example of logging to a custom error object.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling

**Logging in a custom object**

If you get enough emails already, another option would be to use a future method to write a custom object that could catch the error details. Your try-catch would look something like this:

```
global class futureCreateErrorLog {
     @future
     public static void createErrorRecord(string exceptionMessage){
         myErrorObj__c newErrorRecord = new myErrorObj__c();
         newErrorRecord.details__c = exceptionMessage;
         Database.insert(newErrorRecord,false);
     }
}
```

My Queueable class looks something like this.

```
public class TestMyQ implements Queueable
{
    public class MyException Extends Exception{}
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) 
    {
     string JobId;
    try{
            JobId = context.getJobId();
            throw new MyException('Superb Execution and Handling!');
        }
        catch(MyException mex)
        {
            futureCreateErrorLog.createErrorRecord(mex.getMessage(),JobId);         
            throw mex;
        }
    }
  }
```

When I call it using these two lines of code from Execute Anonymous window, I am not seeing anything logged in my error log object.

```
String jobId = System.enqueueJob(new TestMyQ());
System.Debug(jobId);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that `System.enqueueJob` runs the job asynchronously so any `myErrorObj__c` instances created may not appear for some period of time.

But I assume the problem here is that by catching but then re-throwing the exception you are causing the transaction to be rolled back including the recording of the need for the `@future` execution that would do the insert of the `myErrorObj__c`.

Removing:

```
throw mex;
```

should stop that, but it also hides the error from being visible in the normal Apex Job Queue UI.

Also note that governor limit exceptions can't be caught so those exceptions cannot be logged in this way.

Comment: Yes! That was exactly the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to publish a platform event and choose to have it commit before the transaction is rolled back. You can then create a trigger that listens for these error events, and writes them to your custom object.

EDIT: You could also use a Process Builder to listen for the event